# CloudFlare and WWW-less version of the site

Tags: website, redirection

CloudFlare requires a site to be accessible via `WWW` subdomain, which points (via CNAME record) to CF's server. That server grabs and caches content from my non `WWW` version of a site, doesn't it?

So it looks like both version of the site should be accessible and no 301/302 redirects should be performed (previously I redirected `WWW` version to `non WWW` for SEO reasons). So Google bot could see both versions of the site and treat it as different sites, couldn't it?

Can I redirect `non WWW` version of a site to `WWW` version and have CloudFlare works fine?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should enable Cloudflare on the non-WWW domain (it is a simple change on the DNS settings page), and leave the redirect from `www.` domain as it is.

Cloudflare has no requirements on the actual domain name you want to use. If you have used domain without `www.` prefix, it is best to keep it that way, so that you won't lose any SEO-benefits.

Everything will work just fine this way, Cloudflare will cache the non-www -domain.